# Dielectric permitivity as a function of frequency

Tags: electromagnetism

The relationship between the electric displacement $\mathbf{D}$ and electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is:
$$
\mathbf{D} = \epsilon _0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}
$$
where $\mathbf{P}$ is the polarization vector. If the medium is linear:
$$
\mathbf{D} = \epsilon \mathbf{E} \tag{1}
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the permitivity of the medium. This is what I have learned so far from Griffith's electrodynamics book.

A paper I am reading says that $\epsilon$ can be a function of frequency so that $(1)$ becomes:

$$
\mathbf{D} = \epsilon(\omega) \mathbf{E}= [\epsilon_1 (\omega) + i\epsilon_2(\omega)] \mathbf{E}
$$
where $\epsilon _1, \epsilon_2$ are the real and imaginary parts of $\epsilon$

My questions are:

1. What quantity is $\omega$ the frequency of?
2. How does $\omega$ affect the medium permittivity?
3. (possibly related to #2) Why is $\epsilon$ a complex quantity?

Answer (score 0):

Permitivity $\epsilon$ can also be written as:
$$
\epsilon = (1+\chi_e)\epsilon_0
$$

Where $\chi_e$ is the electric susceptibility of the material describing the degree of polarization of the material when in the presence of an electric field.

The susceptibility $\chi_e$ can also be written as a ratio of the polarization $\mathbf{P}$ to electric field strength $\mathbf{E}$:

$$
\chi_e = \frac{\mathbf{P}}{\epsilon_0\mathbf{E}}
$$

If the applied electric field $\mathbf{E}$ or polarization $\mathbf{P}$ is complex then by the above equation, $\chi_e$ would be complex as well. The effect of frequency depends on the specific medium and its polarization characteristics.

1. $\omega$ is a function of the applied field, $\mathbf{E}$
2. Depends on the medium
3. $\epsilon$ can be described as a function of $\chi_e$ which is based on measured polarization and electric field which can be complex

Comment: Isn't it already sufficient to express any electric field as a real function?

Comment: Expressing the electric field as a phasor simplifies many calculations and allow easy expression of the phase component. Consider how phasors are used circuit analysis with capacitors and inductors.

Answer (score 0):

This is useful when a lossy dielectric is hit by a signal,of frequency $\omega$.  By the microscopic version of Ohm’s law, $\vec J=\sigma \vec E$ is a dissipatrice term that is linked to the Maxwell equation
$$
\nabla\times\vec H= \sigma \vec E+ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec D
$$
Assuming that the temporal part of the field is the real part of $e^{i\omega t}$ one then obtains the effective complex permittivity
$$
\epsilon_c=\epsilon-i\frac{\sigma}{\omega}
$$
The imaginary part is related to the attenuation of the wave due to Ohmic losses.

More extensively, we have, under the assumption that the signal is the real part of $\vec H_se^{i\omega t}$ and $\vec E_se^{i\omega t}$ (with $\vec H_s$ and $\vec E_s$ time-independent complex quantities)
\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{\nabla }\times \vec{E}_{s} &=&-i\omega \mu
\vec{H}_{s}, \\
\vec{\nabla }\times \vec{H}_{s} &=&i\omega \varepsilon
_{c}\vec{E}_{s}.
\end{eqnarray}

Take the curl of $\vec{\nabla }\times \vec{E}_{s}:$
\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{\nabla }\times \left( \vec{\nabla }\times \vec{E}_{s}\right)
&=&-i\omega \mu \left( \vec{\nabla }\times \vec{H}_{s}\right)
=-i\omega \mu \left( i\omega
\varepsilon _{c}\vec{E}_{s}\right) , \\
&=&\vec{\nabla }\left( \vec{\nabla }\cdot
\vec{E}_{s}\right) -\nabla ^{2}\vec{E}_{s}, \\
&=&-\nabla ^{2}\vec{E}_{s}
\end{eqnarray}
using vector calculus identities and Maxwell's equations with no source. This produces the final equation
\begin{equation}
-\nabla ^{2}\vec{E}_{s}=\omega ^{2}\mu \varepsilon _{c}%
\vec{E}_{s}.
\end{equation}
Introducing the complex quantity
\begin{equation}
\gamma ^{2}=-\omega ^{2}\mu \varepsilon _{c}=-\omega ^{2}\mu \left(
\varepsilon -i\frac{\sigma }{\omega }\right) ,
\end{equation}
we finally obtain the (complex) wave equation
\begin{equation}
\nabla ^{2}\vec{E}_{s}-\gamma ^{2}\vec{E}_{s}=0. 
\end{equation}
with solution
\begin{align}
\vec{E}_{s} =&\vec{E}_{0}e^{\pm \gamma \hat{n}%
\cdot \vec{r}}, 
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\gamma ^{2} =&-\omega ^{2}\mu \left( \varepsilon -i\frac{\sigma }{\omega }
\right)
=-\omega ^{2}\mu \varepsilon \left( 1-i\frac{\sigma }{\omega \varepsilon }%
\right) , 
\end{align}
Write $\gamma=\alpha+ i\beta$.  The term $e^{\pm \alpha \hat n\cdot\vec r}$ decays with the location $\vec r$ of the field.  $\alpha$ can be found to be
$$
\alpha =\sqrt{\frac{\omega ^{2}\mu \varepsilon }{2}}\left[ \left( 1+\frac{%
\sigma ^{2}}{\omega ^{2}\varepsilon ^{2}}\right) ^{1/2}-1\right] ^{1/2}.
$$
and is this $0$ when the conductivity $\sigma$ of the medium is $0$.  Since $\sigma$ is the conductivity from the microscopic Ohm’s law, and the decay constant $\alpha$ is $0$ when $\sigma=0$ (lossless dielectric), the decay of the signal is related to the Ohmic losses in the medium.

[I hope I didn’t make too many mistakes.  This material is common in most applied E&M books.]

Comment: Could you explain more why $\mathbf{J}$ is dissipative? I don't see why it is the case in the equation for the curl of $\mathbf{H}$